# Behaviour when including the same field twice in entity framework linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

what happens when I include the same field twice, meaningly I take from db an entity and I use the EF `.include` option. What I mean is this:
I have:

```
.Include(x => x.Student)
.Include(x => x.Car)
.Include(x => x.Student)
```

This is the model:

```
Person has a Student
Person has a car
```

so by including (by mistake) the student twice (since my person has ONLY a student), is there an issue?
P.S. I only want it included ONCE! since I have only a single student.
Does ef complain about this? I tried it and it seemed ok, but I do not know the implications of this. Can anyone explain/elaborate? Searched a bit but couldn't identify any issues.

Comment: I believe there should not be any issues, and you are *supposed* to use it like that in fact. I'll try to find the documentation on it.

Comment: My point is that I need ONLY a student. The base entity is a person, therefore it has a single student.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take this sample:

```
public class RentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Rent> Rents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Rent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

A rent contains the Student and the Car.

Lets make a query with unique Include clauses:

```
var rents = ctx.Rents
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    //.Include(x => x.Student)
    .ToList();
```

This is the generated sql:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1],
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name],
[Extent2].[Year] AS [Year],
[Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2],
[Extent3].[Model] AS [Model],
[Extent3].[Price] AS [Price]
FROM   [dbo].[Rents] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Student_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Car_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

Let's make a query duplicating an Include:

```
var rents = ctx.Rents
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .ToList();
```

You'll get this sql:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1],
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name],
[Extent2].[Year] AS [Year],
[Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2],
[Extent3].[Model] AS [Model],
[Extent3].[Price] AS [Price]
FROM   [dbo].[Rents] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Student_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Car_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

As you can see, EF is smart enough to generate the same sql even when you specify an Include more than once.

> UPDATE: Repeated includes (many times)

Let's try this:

```
var rents = ctx.Rents
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Car)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .Include(x => x.Student)
    .ToList();
```

Repeated Includes and several times. And here's the generated sql:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1],
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent2].[Year] AS [Year],
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2],
    [Extent3].[Model] AS [Model],
    [Extent3].[Price] AS [Price]
    FROM   [dbo].[Rents] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Student_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Car_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

Just the same code again. So, yes. We could say it'll be ok, although a little weird thing to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So even if I would include the same entity 30 times (like: `.Include(x => x.Student)`, ef would include it only once and generate the corresponding sql with student included only once?

Comment: @firstlast Indeed! Let's try it out. Check the update.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer, really on the point of it.
And if for the student I want to include the university, can I do
`.Include(x => x.Student).Include(x => x.Student.University)` or can I simply go for a single include, meaningly `.Include(x => x.Student.University)`? Note that all the fields from the Student need to be included, but not all the entities (I do need University).

Comment: When I'll reach rep, I will also up.

Comment: @firstlast you just need to do  .Include(x => x.Student.University) and EF will Join with University also.

Comment: Great. So it does actually do the join with student and then a join with university. Was not sure and when I checked, I saw no difference, but I tought of external impacts

Comment: I appreciate your testing.  We have a class with two dbsets.  One has includes already in it and the other doesn't.  I have a permissions filter that needs three includes and thanks to you all i needed to do was add them in my check without worrying that it would conflict with existing includes.

Answer (score 2):

If you call it twice, the same query will be generated. Result the same, something like this

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
    [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId],
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1],
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[People] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PersonId] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly valid and won't trip up EF in anyway. Consider how you include additional references and collections that hang off a reference like `Student`. You might write them like this. What you have proposed won't confuse EF any more than the following example.

```
.Include(x => x.Student.Teacher)
.Include(x => x.Car)
.Include(x => x.Student.DrivingLog)
```